# Errors (1) missing \endcsname, (2) TeX capacity exceeded when including audio with media9

Tags: errors, media9, capacity

I'm trying to include sound clips in my .tex file.

In a minimal file, I have no problems:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{media9}

\begin{document}
\section{Lyd}
\includemedia[addresource=dodonusman01.mp3,
transparent,
flashvars={source=dodonusman01.mp3&autoPlay=true}]{\bf Here}{APlayer.swf} 
is some sound.
\end{document}
```

However, if I enter the same code in the .tex file I actually want the sound files in, I get first these errors:

```
Extra \endcsname. ....mp3&autoPlay=true}]{\bf Her}{APlayer.swf}

Missing \endcsname inserted. ....mp3&autoPlay=true}]{\bf Here}{APlayer.swf}
```

When I compile again, I get:

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [parameter stack size=10000]. \catcode`\noexpand\^^A
```

The file I tried to include is 15kb. I guess there's a clash with something else I use in my .tex document. Here's my preamble, I've deleted all text as it is 150 pages:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} % references
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{tipa} % ipa
\usepackage{gb4e} % gloss
\usepackage{cgloss4e} % gloss
\usepackage{caption} % table and figure captions
\captionsetup[table]{skip=0pt,font=footnotesize}
\captionsetup[figure]{skip=0pt,font=footnotesize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{marvosym} % play arrow button
\usepackage{media9} % sound files
\usepackage{enumitem} % to make lists with more levels
\setlistdepth{5}

\let\ipa\textipa
\let\cap\textsc
\usepackage{vowel}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
{-2.5ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.25ex}%
{1.25ex \@plus .25ex}%
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4} % how many sectioning levels to assign numbers to
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}    % how many sectioning levels to show in ToC

\usepackage{wrapfig} % to wrap text around figures
\newcommand{\BlankCell}{}
\let\eachwordone=\it
\usepackage{slashbox} % to make tables with slash in upper left field
\usepackage{amssymb}


\newenvironment{dedication} % for the dedication
{\clearpage           % we want a new page
\thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
\vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
\itshape             % the text is in italics
\raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
}
{\par % end the paragraph
\vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
\clearpage           % finish off the page
}

\begin{document}
\section{Test}

\includemedia[addresource=dodonusman01.mp3,
transparent,
flashvars={source=dodonusman01.mp3&autoPlay=true}]{\bfHere}{APlayer.swf} 
is some sound. 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `automath` feature of `gb4e` and the issue can be reproduced with the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{media9} % sound files
\usepackage{gb4e} % gloss
\usepackage{cgloss4e} % gloss

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\includemedia[
  addresource=click.mp3,
  transparent,
  flashvars={source=click.mp3&autoPlay=true}
]{\textbf{Here}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Just add `\noautomath`, as mentioned in the documentation for `gb4e`, section 3, “Varia”.

> • Sub- & superscripts (`_` and `^`) work outside mathmode, too.
>   **Note:** This feature is known to cause problems for a number of other packages. It is retained for backward compatibility. In case of problems, you can disable it by adding the command `\noautomath` in your preamble immediately after loading the gb4e package. You can also re-enable it later with the command `\automath`. [Added 2009/12/28]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{media9} % sound files
\usepackage{gb4e} % gloss
\usepackage{cgloss4e} % gloss
\noautomath % <----------------- Here it is!

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\includemedia[
  addresource=click.mp3,
  transparent,
  flashvars={source=click.mp3&autoPlay=true}
]{\textbf{Here}}{APlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```